# Why I can get a instance of an class that is not referenced in this assembly?

Tags: c#, reflection, interface

**Background**:
We have three assemblies:

- printing (Generates reports as pdfs)
  -> Reference to businessObjects.interfaces
- businessObjects (contains all of our business objects) -> Reference to 
  businessObjects.interfaces
- businessObjects.interfaces (Here we declare the properties for the printing, 
  only properties that are needed are included)
  -> No references

The object is implemented like this:

public interface IDeliveryNote // Assembly: businessObjects.interfaces

public partial class DeliveryNote : IDeliveryNote // Assembly:businessObjects

There is also a class 'Order' inside the DeliveryNote, holding a bool 'IsNeutralDelivery'

**Problem:**
Some report(DeliveryNoterReport) was buggy and we needed to include an existing property (IsNeutralDelivery) from the businessObjects.DeliveryNote.Order - object.
Actually we cant rollout the application (Dont ask :))

While debugging I noticed that from

```
IDeliveryNote dn = ((IDeliveryNote)this.DataSource);
```

i can access also the Order and the needed property (IsNeutralDelivery)
maybe just fancy visual studio magic, so i tried to get the property with reflection like this:

```
bool neutralDeliveryAddressIsNeutralDelivery = (bool)dn.GetType().GetProperty("Order").GetValue(dn).GetType().GetProperty("IsNeutralDelivery").GetValue(dn.GetType().GetProperty("Order").GetValue(dn));
```

And yes, I retrieved the value and with that I could fix the bug (Only replace the printing.dll)

**Question:**
Why I can get a instance of the DeliveryNote object when i got no references to the assembly that it belongs to.

Comment: `There is also a class 'Order' inside the DeliveryNote` - do you mean a property that holds an instance of the class Order?

Comment: Indeed, Deliverynote(class)->Order(class)->IsNeutralDelivery(property)

Comment: Maybe because indirect references are a thing. If you inspect the DLLs in the output folder, there will be one that contains the concrete implementation.

Comment: Good point, I decompiled the dll, not found the assembly (businessObjects ) that is referenced